# XML Clean up (remove invalid characters from attribute value)

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

How can i remove none valid chars from xml but keep standard
for example i want remove all < and " from attribute value inner strings

```
<log>
  <data id="1" name="No Error"  value="0" />
  <data id="2" name="Error "1" between text" value="0" />
  <data id="3" name="Error <2> between text"  value="0"  />
</log>
```

How can i daynamicly remove quotes surrounds "1"
and <> surrounds 2

that final out put shuld be

```
<log>
  <data id="1" name="No Error"  value="0"  />
  <data id="2" name="Error 1 between text" value="0" />
  <data id="3" name="Error 2 between text"  value="0"  />
</log>
```

Thanks for the suppot

I was thinking of the following solution:

1. Read the file as text
2. Modify any string that starts with `<Name=>` and ends with
   `<value=>`
3. remove all `",<,>`
4. add `"` after `<name=>` and add `"` before `<value=>`

if this is correct, how can i do this with C#, the replace method will not work.

Thanks

Comment: Where does the Xml code come from? It sounds to me like this should be fixed in the Xml generator rather than puzzled back together later on.

Comment: Instead of trying to fix this invalid XML, can you fix the program that wrote the XML? It should use a DOM or [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) to produce correct xml.

Comment: Let's get the things straight. Don't be fooled into thinking that you have XML as input. What you have shown has nothing to do with XML. You have some random bit of string characters. A XML by definition means that those bits of string characters must respect certain rules. So either fix the way this string is generated so that it represents a valid XML or if you don't have control over this part notify the author of the code that he has a serious bug in it that needs to be fixed.

Comment: The xml is generated from an exteranl application, the application is a blackbox  and there is no way to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your information I found 2 different ways,

1-

```
public static void ReplaceInvalidCharFromAttribute(string filePath, string startElement, string nextElement, string[] removeStrings)
        {
            string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
                {
                    string line;
                    string temp;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        temp = RemoveInvalidCharFromAttribute(line, startElement, nextElement, removeStrings);
                        sw.WriteLine(temp??line);
                    }
                }
            }

            File.Delete(filePath);
            File.Move(tempFile, filePath);
        }



public static string RemoveInvalidCharFromAttribute(string input, string startElement, string nextElement, string[] invalidChars)
        {
            if (input.IndexOf(startElement) < 0 || input.IndexOf(nextElement) < 0) return null;
            int start =input.IndexOf(startElement) + startElement.Length;
            int end = input.IndexOf(nextElement);
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(input.Substring(start, (end - start)));
            StringBuilder resCopy = new StringBuilder(res.ToString());

            foreach (string inv in invalidChars)
                res.Replace(inv, "");

            // return the result after surrounding the text with double 
            return
                input.Replace(
                resCopy.ToString(),
                (String.Concat("\"", String.Concat(res.ToString().Trim(), "\" "))));
        }
```

2- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316063

so for so good, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

in PHP I use the following to encode the data, before it goes into the XML:-

```
function xml_encode($string)
{
    $string=preg_replace("/&/", "&amp;", $string);
    $string=preg_replace("/</", "&lt;", $string);
    $string=preg_replace("/>/", "&gt;", $string);
    $string=preg_replace("/\"/", "&quot;", $string);
    $string=preg_replace("/%/", "&#37;", $string);

    return utf8_encode($string);
}
```

It will look like you suggest in a browser, until you actually look at the source.

At this point you would need to check for "& amp;" and hex/octal codes.

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Note that this will destroy the original Xml, too, though.

Comment: I changed the example a little to show that this is done to make the XML valid. So you'd need to remove the ENCODED characters.